# Do wormholes have a side to their path through space?

Tags: general-relativity, astrophysics, wormholes

In theory do wormholes have a side to their path through space?

What is there at a point in line with the entry and exit, would anything look different at that point in space?

Could a space ant get in through the side of a wormhole?

Update: The wormhole would be an einstein-rosen bridge from GR. I also wonder if it's torus would radiate Hawking radiation?

Comment: I could imagine this answer depending on what one means mathematically by "wormhole," and it's not like one can point to a "typical" wormhole somewhere in the universe for reference.

Comment: It's hard to imagine. In my mind I think that the closer you got to the path/ torus the closer you would be to the entry and the exit.

Comment: FWIW, there's a discussion about the appearance of a wormhole in space here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/148091/would-a-wormhole-in-space-look-like-anything-at-all/148100